# Professor and textbook disagree on frequency at which a pendulum oscillates

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, oscillators

We had a guest lecturer today who told us that the frequency at which a pendulum oscillates is $\omega=\sqrt{mgL/I}$.

However the textbook states that is $\omega=\sqrt{g/L}$.

Why the discrepancy?

Comment: Physical pendulum versus mathematical pendulum.

Comment: As in simple pendulum vs compound? Or? Also can you post it as an answer?

Comment: Did anyone in the class actually *ask* the guest lecturer about this?  I bet s/he could have explained.

Comment: The variation in nomenclature here is interesting. In the books I learned from it was "simple" versus "physical". The only combination missing at this point is "mathematical" versus "compound".

Comment: @dmckee And then there is the pendulum as a point mass on a massless perfectly Hooke's law string.... and the coupled pendulum... and the double pendulum (chaos)... and the inversion pendulum....

Comment: @user8814, it would benefit you to read ahead in your text book such that you are 1-2 days ahead of the lecture.  You will not understand everything that you read, but you will have seen the material already, and possibly be able to ask moderately informed questions, which the lecturer will appreciate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the kind of pendulum.

The ideal and simplest case is a point mass on a massless string of exactly constant length $L.$ That gives $\omega = \sqrt{g/L}.$ The mathematical pendulum.

A physical pendulum takes inte account that the mass is in an extended rigid body. See http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/pendp.html for the derivation.

Answer (score 7):

For a pendulum consisting of a massless rod holding a point mass $m$, the frequency is $\sqrt{g/L}$. For a pendulum consisting of a possibly-massive rod and non-point mass, where the system has a moment of inertia $I$, the frequency is $\sqrt{mgL/I}$. Note that the moment of inertia of a point mass $m$ attached to a massless rod of length $L$ is $I=mL^2$, so the first expression is a special case of the second one.

Comment: Thank you, that was enlightening. I'd upvote if I could.